# Passing variables to arg in Ant Script

Tags: ant

I've the following Ant command. I need to pass a variable `{merged.folder}` to the arg line. This value comes from a property file. But it is not resolving that variable. Is there any way to do this. Can you please help me?

```
<java fork="true" dir="${shrinksafe.util.path}/buildscripts" classname="org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main">
    <arg line="releaseDir=${merged.folder}" />
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${shrinksafe.util.path}/shrinksafe/js.jar" />
        <pathelement location="${shrinksafe.util.path}/shrinksafe/shrinksafe.jar" />
        <pathelement path="${java.class.path}" />
    </classpath>
</java>
```

Comment: Maybe a simple dollar sign will solve it? ${merged.folder}?

Comment: Ohhh...That was a typo in my code. I did try with $. But that did not work

Comment: @Apps There is no such thing as not resolving a variable. If this was the case no ant script would ever work. It is more probable that your variable is not defined somewhere. Try to echo it just before you used it and see the result.

Comment: You should definitely try `<echo message="${merged.folder}">` to see if there's a different value or anything, but in any case - can you explain what you mean by "This value comes from a property file"? Does the ant script parse the file?

Comment: is it only ${merged.folder} that is not resolved, or all variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked this ant script based on your post:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project default="test_arg_path" basedir=".">
    <property file="props.properties"/>

    <target name="test_arg_path">
        <java dir=".\build\classes" classname="Test">
            <!-- <arg value="${argValue}"/>--> <!-- First variant -->
            <arg line="releaseDir=${argValue} arg2Value" /> <!-- Second variant -->
        </java>
    </target>
</project>
```

Property file ***props.properties***:

```
argValue=argVal
```

***Test*** class source:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("args is empty");
        }
        System.out.println(Test.class + ", arg0: " + args[0]);

        if (args.length > 1) {
            System.out.println(Test.class + ", arg1: " + args[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

The output for first variant (using arg value):

> class Test, arg0: argVal

The output for second variant (using arg line):

> class Test, arg0: releaseDir=argVal 
>   class Test, arg1: arg2Value

As you can see, the everything is OK with your script and it is correct. The problem, I think, in value setting of your variable `merged.folder`